# Want get value of other list where value matched

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, string-comparison

I have two lists which are following.

```
characteristic  = ['length', 'width', 'height', 'Thread length', 'space']
value = ['length 34','width ab23','Thread length 8ah','space','height 099']
```

I have written a loop.

```
temp_str = {}



for x in characteristic:

  for z in value:  

      if x in z:

        temp_str = z.replace(x,'')

        temp_str += ','

        print(temp_str)
```

I am getting output:

```
34,
Thread  8ah,
 ab23,
 099,
 8ah,
,
```

but in real I want output like following

```
34,ab23,099,8ah,
```

Comment: I think you are just missing the fact that `"length"` appears in both `"length"` and `"Thread length"`

Comment: You should be able to just unindent the `print` and do that after the loop

Comment: @Cresht I know there are two lengths. Can you write a loop for me?

Comment: @Sayse It is not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
characteristic  = ['length', 'width', 'height', 'Thread length', 'space']
value = ['length 34','width ab23','Thread length 8ah','space','height 099']
temp_str = ''

for x in characteristic:
    for z in value:  
        if z.startswith(x) and z!=x:
            temp_str += z.split(' ')[-1]
            temp_str += ','
print(temp_str)
```

Output:

```
34,ab23,099,8ah,
```

Note: `space` was ignored because it was not included in your required output